# CSS - if text contains no spaces it makes horizontal scroll inside tab div

Tags: html, css

My css rule for the div:

```css
.message-body {
    background: #5181a2;
    padding: 8px 5px;
    text-align: justify;
}
```

I want to render this text inside the div like **'hello hello'** is in previous line.

[image]

Comment: Which "this text" are you referring to? You have three `div` elements visible in your screenshot, apparently.

Answer (score 2):

Use `word-break` property:

```
.message-body {
    background: #5181a2;
    padding: 8px 5px;
    text-align: justify;
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

Comment: Preferably use overflow-wrap: break-word; since it will only break a word if it is really necessary.

Comment: Thanks for your help